# Python programming about list

Tags: python, list, loops

In this program I want to remove the duplicate values from the list. This is what i wrote:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

def loop():
    for a in range(len(list)-1):
        for b in range(a+1,len(list)):
            if list[a] == list[b]:
                del list[a]
    print(list)  
loop()
```

But, it's giving me this error:

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: It's because you are deleting items while you are looping through the list, create a new list with only the items you want. If you want to remove duplicates you can just do `list(set(listName))`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `numpy` then you can do (I renamed your list to `l` to avoid ambiguity):

```
import numpy as np 
l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
l_no_duplicates = list( np.unique(l) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The common approach to get a unique collection of items is to use a set. Sets are unordered collections of distinct objects.

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
newList = list(set(list))
```

> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 34, 21, 55, 89]

Answer (score -1):

Do something like the following:

```
create new_list
for item in list:
    if item not in new_list:
        add item to new_list
list = new_list
```

In Python:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

print list
new_list = []
for item in list:
    if item not in new_list:
        new_list.append(item)
list = new_list
print list
```

Now run `python filename.py` and you will see the difference between two lists.